# Grouping the Elements of a Flux by Time

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Suppose I have a real-time stock quote streaming service, which has an endpoint that returns a `Flux<Quote>`.  This is real-time streaming data, and it has content-type of `text/event-stream`.

I want to create a service that subscribes to this data, and performs aggregate operations on groups of `Quote`s, such as the total volume, high, and low over the time period.  These groups will be grouped by time.  I also want this to be a real-time stream, which returns a summary of the quotes received per unit time, as each time period elapses.

My question is how do I do this?  I've tried using `Flux::groupBy` and `Flux::collectList` or similar, but this waits for the stream to complete before emitting aggregate results for each time block.  In a continuous stream of quotes, this will result in my service never emitting anything.

Comment: By "grouped by time", do you mean grouped by a time property in the Quote object, or do you mean grouped by the time it is received at your service? For the latter you can use [`Flux.window`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#window-java.time.Duration-) to group your items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by subscribing to the `Flux<Quote>` stream from the streaming service, and then publishing to a Sink.  Like this:

```
public class QuoteAggregatorService {

    private Sinks.Many<AggregateQuote> aggregateSink = Sinks.many()
                             .multicast()
                             .onBackpressureBuffer();
    private AggregateQuote aggregateQuote = new AggregateQuote();
    private long groupTime = 0L;
    private ProducerClient producerClient; // Spring reactive WebClient client to the streaming quote service


    public Flux<AggregateQuote> getAggregateQuotes() {
        producerClient.getQuotes(symbol)
            .doOnNext(q -> {
                if (getGroupTime(q) > groupTime) {
                    emitQuote();
                    aggregateQuote = new AggregateQuote();
                    groupTime = getGroupTime(q); // rounds to nearest minute
                }
                aggregateQuote.processQuote(q); // updates the aggregate values including volume, open, high, low, etc.
            })
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                emitQuote(); // have to emit the last aggregate quote on complete, otherwise it gets skipped
                aggregateSink.tryEmitComplete(); // signals to the caller that the Flux has completed.
            })
            .subscribe();
            return aggregateSink.asFlux();
    }

    private void emitQuote() {
        aggregateSink.tryEmitNext(aggregateQuote);
    }
}
```